# Diff Util dispatchUpdatesTo not dispatching updates to RecyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have a list that I'm sorting by one of two different variables, the name of the object and the date of the object. I have a sort button in the action bar with a popup that lets you choose which sorting method to use. Selecting one of these options notifies the adapter to use a new comparator to sort the list, as long as the comparators aren't the same.

The default sorting is by name, and when I switch to sorting by date the list updates just fine. However, when I try to switch back to sorting by name, the dispatchUpdatesTo method does not seem to dispatch the updates to the adapter, even though I can see the comparing lists are different and DiffUtil has correctly identified a change. Here is what the result is, as you can see detectMoves is true:[image: diffResult]

Anyone know any reason my adapter wouldn't be updating? I can post code if needed, but I think it's pretty straightforward

Comment: Before calling the `DiffUtil.callback(oldList, newList)` did you compare If the two lists were the same or not?